# How to creat an input group with buttons instead of radio buttons but still have only one of them selected?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to emulate the behaviour of radio buttons withing a bootstrap `form-group` so a line in a form has several buttons (`"btn btn-info"` for example), with the buttons being able to be "selected", but only one of them can be selected at a given moment.

If I just insert two `input` elements I get buttons, but they cannot be selected, just pressed.

Example (that does not work for me...)

```
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label for="Section" style="text-align:right">Section</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <label align=center>
                                <input class="btn btn-info" name="Section" id="Non-Smoking" value="Non-Smoking">
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="btn btn-warning" name="Section" id="Smoking" value="Smoking">
                            </label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="radio"` to your `input`s?

Comment: I did, this turns the buttons into small radio-buttons (circles) instead of buttons, not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: Yep, that solved it. Thanks!!! @Wavemaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official site suggest to use the `button.js` provided by bootstrap.

Take a look here: [getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio)

> Add data-toggle="buttons" to a .btn-group containing checkbox or radio
>   inputs to enable toggling in their respective styles.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

The above snippet works with a standard bootstrap installation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as @Wavemaster answered in the comment:
The answer is at:
[getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio)